# How to listen parallel two users?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I have next code:

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'd',
  description: 'test',
  execute(client, message, args) {
    const Discord = module.require("discord.js");
    
      message.channel.send("Yes or no?")

      let player1 = '0';
      function firstListen() {
        const collector1 = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === 'HERE_ID_PLAYER_1', { time: 10000 });
        collector1.on('collect', message => {
          if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "yes") {
            player1 = 'yes';
            message.channel.send("Player 1 chose YES");
          } else if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "no") {
            player1 = 'no';
            message.channel.send("Player 1 chose NO");
          }
        })
      };

      let player2 = '0';
      function secondListen() {
        const collector2 = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === 'HERE_ID_PLAYER_2', { time: 10000 });
        collector2.on('collect', message => {
          if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "yes") {
            player2 = 'yes';
            message.channel.send("Player 2 chose YES");
          } else if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "no") {
            player2 = 'no';
            message.channel.send("Player 2 chose NO");
          }
        })
      };

      async function runListen() {
        message.channel.send('start');
        await firstListen();
        await secondListen();
        await message.channel.send(`Player 1 chose ${player1} and Player 2 chose ${player2}`);
      }

      runListen();

    }
  }
```

First, I wanna send message from bot "Yes or no?",
then wanna wait until both of users answer "yes" or "no", or until time is up,
and only after that wanna send final result "Player1 chose yes/no and Player2 chose yes/no"
But cant understand how working with .then in js, or how correctly use async/await..(
Cause, Player2 can answer quicker than Player1. Need to listen both of user parallel, and they must have common timer (for ex.: 10sec for both).
PS: i have 3 question:

1. How I can get result from each function after users chose something? (to do something with their choice)
2. How I can wait until both functions are finish, and only after that send message with results?
3. How I can catch when time is over? and send "Player1, Time is up" or "Player2, Time is up"

Comment: A possible approach is to create a `while` loop that is always `true`, then have events for both player1 and player2 that on message.channel.send set `answer_player_1` and `answer_player_2` to "true", if `answer_player_1 and answer_player_2 are both true` then break loop. You would also have a timeout/counter set as well at the invocation of `runListen`, once that timeout is reached, have it break the `while` loop (so either both players answering break the loop or the timeout breaks the loop)

Look at [eventEmitters](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) for examples.

Comment: @Manny - A polling while loop will not work in nodejs as it will block the event loop and NONE of the other events will get processed.

Comment: UPDATE: Q#3: How I can catch when time is over? and send "Player1, Time is up" or "Player2, Time is up"   
Answer is:    
`collector2.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
        if ((reason === 'time') && (result === '0')) {
          result = 'time';
          message.channel.send('Time is up!');
        }
      });`

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you for that guidance and explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all!
Answer was: need to use promise, and promise.all)

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'd',
  description: 'test',
  async execute(client, message, args) {
    const Discord = module.require("discord.js");
    message.channel.send("Yes or no?")

    var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const collector1 = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === '568481051895136278', { max: 1, time: 10000 });
      collector1.on('collect', message => {
        if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "yes") {
          resolve('yes');
          message.channel.send("Player 1 chose YES");
        } else if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "no") {
          resolve('no');
          message.channel.send("Player 1 chose NO");
        }
      })
      collector1.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
        if (reason === 'time') {
          resolve('time');
          message.channel.send('Player 1, Time is up!');
        }
      });
    });
    var p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const collector2 = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === '568481051895136279', { max: 1, time: 10000 });
      collector2.on('collect', message => {
        if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "yes") {
          resolve('yes');
          message.channel.send("Player 2 chose YES");
        } else if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "no") {
          resolve('no');
          message.channel.send("Player 2 chose NO");
        }
      })
      collector2.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
        if (reason === 'time') {
          resolve('time');
          message.channel.send('Player 2, Time is up!');
        }
      });
    });

    Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(values => {
      console.log(values);
    });

  }
}
```